# Filtering items in one collection which do not exist in another collection - LINQ way

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Currently I'm looking for the efficient solution on how to filter items from one collection which do not exist in another collection using linq.
So far I came up to the following option:

```
class ConrolAccount
        {
            public string ControlName { get; set; }

            public string NaturalAccount { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var defaultAccounts = new List<ConrolAccount>
            {
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "71300", ControlName = "Income Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "70900", ControlName = "AP Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "71600", ControlName = "Cost Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "20200", ControlName = "Trust Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "71800", ControlName = "Tax Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "72000", ControlName = "Undeposited Funds"}
            };

            var existingAccounts = new List<ConrolAccount>
            {
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "70900", ControlName = "AP Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "71600", ControlName = "Cost Control"},
                new ConrolAccount {NaturalAccount = "72000", ControlName = "Undeposited Funds"}
            };

            IEnumerable<string> missedAccounts = defaultAccounts
                .GroupJoin(existingAccounts, d => d.ControlName, e => e.ControlName, (d, accounts) => new {d, accounts})
                .Where(a => !a.accounts.Any())
                .Select(a => a.d.ControlName);

            foreach (string controlName in missedAccounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(controlName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

This will output:

> Income Control
>   Trust Control
>   Tax Control

Here is the link to sandbox: http://rextester.com/EBLZ71941

Could it be done more efficient with linq? Or could someone suggest more faster algorithm without using linq?

Comment: In terms of performance, this solution seems to be good. It doesn't enumerate collections quadratically and must be close to linear on sum of accounts (I guess). However, it can be improved syntatically since you actually only need `ControlName` values.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only interested in the `ControlName` property an `Except` would be more efficient:

```
IEnumerable<string> missedAccounts = defaultAccounts.Select(a => a.ControlName)
    .Except(existingAccounts.Select(a => a.ControlName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do You  know about `Intersect()` and `Except()` predefined functions?

`Intersect()` - find the common item in between two lists/collections

`Except()` - find the item except the items in the first collection(define as per  the order)